How is this dwm source code snippet not throwing an error?
Following the dwm source code from main(), inside checkotherwm
xerrorxlib = XSetErrorHandler(xerrorstart);

, with xerrorxlib defined as
static int (*xerrorxlib)(Display *, XErrorEvent *);

, sets xerrorxlib (a global variable) to NULL as this is the first call to XSetErrorHandler so there is no previous handler to return. Then a few calls later, there's
XSetErrorHandler(xerror);

with xerror defined as:
xerror(Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ee)
{
    if (ee->error_code == BadWindow
    || (ee->request_code == X_SetInputFocus && ee->error_code == BadMatch)
    || (ee->request_code == X_PolyText8 && ee->error_code == BadDrawable)
    || (ee->request_code == X_PolyFillRectangle && ee->error_code == BadDrawable)
    || (ee->request_code == X_PolySegment && ee->error_code == BadDrawable)
    || (ee->request_code == X_ConfigureWindow && ee->error_code == BadMatch)
    || (ee->request_code == X_GrabButton && ee->error_code == BadAccess)
    || (ee->request_code == X_GrabKey && ee->error_code == BadAccess)
    || (ee->request_code == X_CopyArea && ee->error_code == BadDrawable))
        return 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "dwm: fatal error: request code=%d, error code=%d\n",
        ee->request_code, ee->error_code);
    return xerrorxlib(dpy, ee); /* may call exit */
}

Notice the return xerrorxlib(dpy, ee);. How does this not error? Isn't xerrorxlib NULL hence this evaluating to NULL(dpy, ee)?

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/default-handlers.html

XSetErrorHandler will return the previous error handler. Previous error handler is not equal to user-defined handler. So xerrorxlib is equal to previous Xlib error handler here.
